# Input string was not in a correct format - calculating total of labels

Tags: c#

Basically the first for statement below creates a list of testvalue labels depending on the user input.

The second for statement is supposed to work out the total of the dynamic labels created but when i play it i get an error saying "Input string was not in a correct format." relating to       `tots += double.Parse(value[p].ToString());` Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
ArrayList value = new ArrayList();

int p =0;

for (int i = 0; i < weight.Count; i++)
{
    Label test = new Label();
    System.Drawing.Point l8 = new System.Drawing.Point(440, 48 + s);
    test.Location = l8;
    value.Add(test);

    k += 35;

    Label l2 = testpercent1[i] as Label;
    Double.TryParse(l2.Text.Trim(), out label2);
    Label l = testpercent2[i] as Label;
    Double.TryParse(l.Text.Trim(), out label1);
    Double testvalue = Math.Round(((label1 * .3) + (label2 * .4)));
    test.Text = testvalue.ToString();
}

Double total = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < value.Count; p++)
{
    tots += double.Parse(value[p].ToString());
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown what `value` is at all, let alone `value[p]`.

Comment: @Hashey100, do you have particular reason to use `l` as name of variable so it looks like 1, especially in context like `l8` and `l2`? Please try to avoid `l`,`I` and `O` as names of variables and methods for code that you expect to be read by other people.

Comment: @Hashey100: And why are you converting it to a string and then parsing it? What is the value of `value[p]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tots += double.Parse(((Label)value[p]).Text);
```

Comment: You don't need use ToString().

Answer (score 1):

value[p] is of type Label.  If you want to get the text value of the label, you should use value[p].Text.

```
Double total = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < value.Count; p++)
{
   tots += double.Parse(((Label)value[p]).Text);
}
```

Another thing, you should use `List<Label>` for value instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse the `ToString()` of a label. Were you instead looking to parse some property of the label?

When you call `value[p]`, whats being returned is a on object of type `Label`. If you wanted to parse the text of the label your code would instead be

`tots += double.Parse(((Label)value[p]).Text);`

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious you are adding a control to the ArrayList. So this don't work:

```
tots += double.Parse(value[p].ToString());
```

I reccomend you to do:

```
value.Add(test.Text);
```

Then:

```
tots += double.Parse(value[p]);
```

**PS:**
Please use a `List<string>` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Storing your data in labels is a very bad idea. Use a data structure that is better suited for this purpose like an array or a list of doubles. Only use the lables for displaying the data.

```
double[] values = new double[N];
Label[] lables = new Label[N]; // Only for display!

//  Calculate (just as an example)
double result = values[i] + values[k];

// NOT LIKE THIS!
double result = Double.Parse(labels[i]) + Double.Parse(labels[k]);
```